# Где держать бизнес-логику приложения?

Tags: php, mvc

Только начал изучение шаблона MVC и сразу столкнулся с проблемой его понятия.
Перечитал достаточно статей, но так и не нашел единого подхода. Вопрос: где именно необходимо хранить логику приложения, в моделях или контроллерах?

Comment: Я конечно не спец по MVC, но разве контроллер не отвечает за то, чтобы отделить модель от вида?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller
Наиболее частые ошибки
Начинающие программисты очень часто трактуют архитектурную модель MVC как пассивную модель[неизвестный термин] MVC: модель выступает исключительно совокупностью функций для доступа к данным, а контроллер содержит бизнес-логику. В результате — код моделей по факту является средством получения данных из СУБД, а контроллер — типичным модулем, наполненным бизнес-логикой. В результате такого понимания — MVC-разработчики стали писать код, который Pádraic Brady (известный в кругах сообщества «Zend Framework») охарактеризовал как «ТТУК» («Толстые, тупые, уродливые контроллеры»; Fat Stupid Ugly Controllers):

Среднестатистический ТТУК получал данные из БД (используя уровень абстракции базы данных, делая вид, что это модель) или манипулировал, проверял, записывал, а также передавал данные в Представление. Такой подход стал очень популярен потому, что использование таких контроллеров похоже на классическую практику использования отдельного php-файла для каждой страницы приложения.

— [http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2008/12/the-m-in-mvc-why-models-are-misunderstood-and-unappreciated/ The M in MVC: Why Models are Misunderstood and Unappreciated
Но в объектно-ориентированном программировании используется[кем?] активная модель[неизвестный термин] MVC, где модель — это не только совокупность кода доступа к данным и СУБД, но и вся бизнес-логика; также, модели могут инкапсулировать в себе другие модели. Контроллеры же, — как элементы информационной системы, — ответственны лишь за:

приём запроса от пользователя;
анализ запроса;
выбор следующего действия системы, соответственно результатам анализа (например, передача запроса другим элементам системы).
Только в этом случае контроллер становится «тонким» и выполняет исключительно функцию связующего звена (glue layer) между отдельными компонентами информационной системы.

Comment: В таком случае не ясно, почему популярные фреймворки (Laravel, Symphony) используют указанный вами подход **ТТУК**

Comment: Так происходит потому что модель в этих фреймворках - это сущность ORM, по принципу один экземпляр - одна запись в БД. Но реально моделью может быть любой класс который содержит одну единицу какой-то сущности, и может содержать методы манипуляции с этой сущностью. Например, есть сущность User. И в нем есть метод confirmRegistration, который обновит не только одно поле isConfirmed, но и сделает некие другие манипуляции, например - сгенерирует событие. Кроме того, например, нельзя проставть юзеру isConfirmed, если ему не отправлялся запрос на подтверждение, следовательно,

Comment: запрос обновления должен содержать в себе еще и проверку связанной таблицы. Вы может всё это поместить и в контроллер: сначала сделать проверку есть ли запрос на подверждение, затем обновить поле isConfirmed, затем сгенерировать событие, но можно в модели сделать метод: confirm(). И в контроллере вызвать try{$user->confirm();) catch(){...} Это простой пример, но иногда такие манипуляции с моделью могут занимать много строк кода и вызываться в разных местах не один раз, и в этом случае варианта два: или вынести эти манипуляции в какой-то хелпер, или поместить в модель.

Comment: Популярные фреймворки используют данный подход потому что только программист может описать бизнес-логику в модели, она всегда разная, а фреймворк может оперировать только анемичными моделями. Из анемичности модели (раз) и повального увлечения типовым CRUD (два) и вытекает перенос упора на логику в контроллерах. Так что в ответе всё правильно расписано, лайк.