# Где правильнее организовать сложную бизнес-логику Laravel проекта?

Tags: php, laravel

Предположим, что мне необходимо провести некоторые манипуляции с данными, и передать конечный набор в представление (для вывода на страницу, к примеру). Если затолкать все в методы контроллера, то получится как описывают тут [Где держать бизнес-логику приложения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890524/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) . **Подскажите пожалуйста, где лучше организовать такую логику?** До этого я просто использовал методы контроллера. Всем большое спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

В MVC как правило в моделях происходит всё что касается данных.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А вы не могли бы привести пример проекта? Может где-нибудь на гитхабе видели?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте промежуточный слой для бизнес-логики, например service

Comment: Интересный подход, спасибо! Можете привести пример проекта с гитхаба, если видели такой?